# Stretch transparent background to a certain point

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using bootstrap. Now I have a section like this: 
[image]

Now what I would like is for it to have a transparent background. But only upto the width marked with red line. 
[image]

This is the code:

```
.btrcontainer {
    padding-top: 25px;
    padding-bottom: 25px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}
```

But it makes entire row as transparent. I would like it only up to that mark. Tried `background-size` property. Can someone please help?

Comment: My biggest piece of advice: don't use bootstrap. It's a client-side framework created by server-side guys. When you're learning how to do something always learn the base core language or "vanilla" version. Also you're going to need to post more code for any one to really help you out here.

Comment: I don't think this is possible with css. The best way is probably to do this with an image editor

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a linear gradient

This one is transparent to 50% after which it gradually changes color until it reaches `rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3)` at the end.

```css
.btrcontainer {
  padding-top: 25px;
  height: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 25px;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, transparent 50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3));
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}
```

```html
<div class="btrcontainer"></div>
```

This one does something similar but ramps from transparent at 50% until it's completely black at 80% then stays that way.

```css
.btrcontainer {
  padding-top: 25px;
  height: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 25px;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, transparent 50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 80%);
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}
```

```html
<div class="btrcontainer"></div>
```

Comment: You can add one more stopper at start point as dark shade, to make some thing like - 101 (1-black,0-semi transparent).

Answer (score 0):

That transparent div overlays on that background image

you can separate into two section with percentage on width

and set first div to be transparent

and add css on other div whatever you want its separated now.

Hope helps !